# create new df column selecting max column based off if else statement

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "CLIENT" : ['BOB', 'MIKE', 'LOWRY', 'JON', 'KEVIN', 'MARK', 'DAN', 'STEVE', 'ROBERT', 'JAMES'],
    "J1" : [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2],
    "J2" : [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4],
    "J3" : [2, 2, 1, 4, 5, 2, 4, 3, 1, 2],
    "J1_KEY" : [123, 456, 789, 101, 121, 223, 556, 889, 111, 131],
    "J2_KEY" : [1123, 1456, 1789, 1101, 1121, 1223, 1556, 1889, 1111, 1131],
    "J3_KEY" : [2123, 2456, 2789, 2101, 2121, 2223, 2556, 2889, 2111, 2131]
})
```

First I'm trying to find the column that has the highest value from columns: J1,J2,J3

I use the following logic:

```
df[['J1','J2','J3']].idxmax(axis=1)
```

Subsequently, based off the column which has the highest value, grab its respective keys (from columns: J1_KEY, J2_KEY, J3_KEY)

which I tried doing like this:

```
df['client_key'] = if df[['J1','J2','J3']].idxmax(axis=1) == 'J1':
    return df['J1_KEY']
elif df[['J1','J2','J3']].idxmax(axis=1) == 'J2':
    return df['J2_KEY']
elif df[['J1','J2','J3']].idxmax(axis=1) == 'J3':
    return df['J3_KEY']
else:
    return df['J1_KEY']
```

But I get a SyntaxError: invalid syntax.

Any help appreciated, also am I approaching this the most pythonic way?

Comment: Because your DataFrame is not valid Python. Also note that `idxmax(axis=1)` returns a Series

Comment: Fixed the dataframe for you, also you want to work on the series that comes out of the idmax function, then iterate through that with the correct offset.

Comment: Two problems: 1) you're using `return` outside a function and 2) you're directly assigning a conditional to a column. If you want to use your code as it is, I recommend to create a variable to store the values from your conditional, then assign this variable to `df['client_key']`. Best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```py
idx_keys = df[['J1','J2','J3']].idxmax(axis=1) + '_KEY'
df['client_key'] = [df.at[idx,key] for idx,key in idx_keys.iteritems()]
```

Output:

```
   CLIENT  J1  J2  J3  J1_KEY  J2_KEY  J3_KEY  client_key
0     BOB   1   1   2     123    1123    2123        2123
1    MIKE   1   2   2     456    1456    2456        1456
2   LOWRY   2   3   1     789    1789    2789        1789
3     JON   1   1   4     101    1101    2101        2101
4   KEVIN   1   2   5     121    1121    2121        2121
5    MARK   3   3   2     223    1223    2223         223
6     DAN   3   3   4     556    1556    2556        2556
7   STEVE   2   2   3     889    1889    2889        2889
8  ROBERT   3   4   1     111    1111    2111        1111
9   JAMES   2   4   2     131    1131    2131        1131
```